# incorrect time returned in laravel

Tags: php, datetime

This is a strange problem

I am using date functions to get time too but it returns wrong time

```
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This returns `2017-4-21 09:41:44` but the current time is `14:41:44`
There is something wrong with `hours`.
I tried `NOW()` in MySQL and it gave me correct timing but laravel PHP did  not. Can someone help?

Comment: check your timezone

Comment: Configure your time zone on your server... http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Comment: Go to _Config->App_ and search for "timezone"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In laravel project go to `project/config` there is a file `app.php`, in this file search for:

```
'timezone' => '';
```

pass your timezone value in it like:

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata', // I am using this for India
```

And try again, now you will get the correct time as per your timezone.

**Note:** After passing the timezone value run the command `php artisan config:cache` to clear the cache so that you get the updated data.

[Timezone list reference](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 3):

You can set your timezone in the [Laravel config files](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L67). The default value is `UTC`.

Make sure this is set to your correct timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using Laravel Forge you can change the default time zone for your server.