Laravel Job Logs Show Incorrect Time - How to Synchronize Time Zones?
I’m facing a small issue with time zones in my Laravel application and would appreciate your help. I have a scheduled job in Laravel that updates event statuses. The job logs show the following timestamps in the laravel.log file:

[2024-08-19 09:58:18] local.INFO: Success: Checked at 2024-08-19 09:58:18  
[2024-08-19 09:58:18] local.INFO: Number of events updated to 'En cours': 0  
[2024-08-19 09:58:18] local.INFO: Number of events updated to 'Terminé': 4  

However, the actual local time is 10:58, not 09:58. I’ve checked the following:
Server Time Zone:
The server time zone is set correctly.
Laravel Configuration:
In config/app.php, I have:
php
Copy code
'timezone' => 'UTC',
I need the log times to reflect my local time zone (e.g., Central European Time). What should I change in my Laravel configuration or code to ensure that the job logs show the correct local time?
I want the job logs to reflect the local time zone (e.g., Central Africa Time) instead of UTC. How can I configure Laravel or the server to ensure that the job logs display the correct local time?

have you restarted you queue worker after changing the timezone in config/app.php ?

Which Laravel version are you using? If you are using Laravel 11 there should be a key called APP_TIMEZONE which defaults to UTC.
If this is not the case, and you are using an older version of Laravel, you should check out this answer on another question which is related to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539446/16909735
Also, a good reference from the other post is the timezone list reference from the PHP documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
